# Use of WHERE with IIF, or is HAVING Preferred?

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a WHERE statement that produces values in a field depending on two conditions. I then want to modify another column depending on what is returned from the new column.

In Code - the below selects employees locations if they exist and stores them in a field titled 'Location'

```
SELECT e.*,
(SELECT l.[Location]
FROM Locations as l
WHERE e.[ID] = l.[ID] AND e.[Team] is NULL
) as L
FROM Employees as e
```

I then want to perform an IIF (or possibly HAVING() or SWITCH()?) based on the contents of this new 'Location' field to edit the Team column of the employee based on their Location.

In pseudocode:

```
IIF(L = 'Germany', Team Field = 'Operations'),
ANOTHER IIF
```

or perhaps another function is better suited as mentioned above. I'm not understanding how to 'grab' the result of the above where (i.e. the Location field) and use that in a conditional statement

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iif()`:

```
SELECT e.*,
       (SELECT IIF(Locations = 'X', [Old Locations Field], 'Y')
        FROM Locations as l
        WHERE e.[ID] = l.[ID] AND e.[Marker] is NULL
       ) as Locations
FROM Employees as e;
```

If this accomplishes what you need, then it is a fine approach.

Comment: I've updated my question as i think my exampling was confusing. I am looking at each employee. If their Team field is emply, i get their location. The IIF() then comes in when I am trying to write back into the Team field a 'hard coded' Team name based on their location.